# How to write link to wait for an element to be displayed?

Tags: c#, linq, selenium

I am having trouble with syntax when trying to use Linq. Simply I want to check that if an element contains a piece of text ,then wait for that text to be displayed and then click on it. This is because the element I am looking for is in a slider so I need to wait for the slider to display the relevant text before in order to be able to select it.

How can i write this as the below is incorrect as acannot conver bool to OpenQA.selenium.By

```
public void SelectReasonsToBookWithUsLinks(string itemName, string linkText)
{
    var ReasonsBookWithUsLinks = _driver.FindElements(HomepageResponsiveElements.BookWithUsLinks);

    if (ReasonsBookWithUsLinks.Any(x => x.Text == linkText))
    {                            
        _driver.WaitForElementToExist(ReasonsBookWithUsLinks.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Text == linkText).Displayed, 120);
        ReasonsBookWithUsLinks.Single(x => x.Text ==linkText).Click();
    }
}
```

Update:

WaitForElementToExist Method:

```
 public static IWebElement WaitForElementToExist(this IWebDriver driver, By locator, int waitSeconds)
    {
      return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double) waitSeconds)).Until<IWebElement>(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(locator));
    }
```

Comment: Could you show your code for _driver.WaitForElementToExist method?

Comment: @rs232 Have included it now in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Click` method will raise an exception is the targeted element is not displayed or interactable, and `Single` will raise `System.InvalidOperationException` if there's no single match.

So you could simply wrap the action in a waiter which will retry until there's no exception of the expected kind:

```
public void SelectReasonsToBookWithUsLinks(string itemName, string linkText) {
    var wait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(_driver);
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(
      typeof(System.InvalidOperationException),
      typeof(InvalidElementStateException),
      typeof(ElementNotVisibleException),
      typeof(StaleElementReferenceException)
    );

    wait.Until(drv => {
        drv.FindElements(HomepageResponsiveElements.BookWithUsLinks)
           .Single(elm => elm.Text == linkText)
           .Click();
        return true;
      });
}
```